# Why can"t I render PNG after rendering the animation?

Tags: rendering

I rendered my Cycles animation in OpenEXR format.

Now I made some changes and want to render a single frame, but as soon as I hit <kbd>F12</kbd> it just shows me the render of the frame which was rendered in the animation. I tried changing slots for the render too.

Comment: Are you using the Video Sequencer in the same file as your 3D scene? you should better use another file dedicated to video editing, or go into the Output panel > Post Processing and disable Compositing